# How do i use MMX mulH and mulL for two 64 bit integers to get one 128 bit integer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arbitrary-precision, mmx

[Hello, I'm working on yet another arbitrary precision integer library.](https://github.com/Mr-Bossman/infINT) I wanted to implement multiplication but I got stuck when `_m_pmulhw` in `<mmintrin.h>` just didn't work. there is very little [documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3968,4340,4341,4339,4333,4014,4340,4339,4012,4013,4014,4340,4340&cats=Arithmetic&techs=MMX) on MMX instructions. When I test it out, it just gives me gibberish when I multiply two UINT64_MAXs.

```
uint_fast64_t mulH(const uint_fast64_t &a, const uint_fast64_t &b)  {  
    return (uint_fast64_t)_m_pmulhw((__m64)a,(__m64)b);
}
uint_fast64_t mulL(const uint_fast64_t &a, const uint_fast64_t &b)  {  
    return (uint_fast64_t)_m_pmullw((__m64)a,(__m64)b);
}
int main() {
    uint64_t a = UINT64_MAX;
    uint64_t b = UINT64_MAX;
    std::cout <<  std::bitset<64>(mulH(a,b)) << std::bitset<64>(mulL(a,b));
}

output: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000100000000000000010000000000000001
```

I don't know why it's not working i have an A6-4400M APU...

[coreinfo's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/coreinfo) output:`MMX             *       Supports MMX instruction set`

So I think I can say, it isn't unsupported. If anyone can give me some tips on how to make this work thanks.

Compiler: gcc

IDE: visual studio code

Comment: Did you take a look at VS’s [intrinsics list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list), in particular [`_umul128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `_m_pmulhw` does. It's actually very clearly documented on Intel's Intrinsics Guide: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_m_pmulhw&expand=4340. The corresponding instruction is `pmulhw`, which is also clearly documented on e.g. Felix Cloutier's x86 instructions guide: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhw

It multiplies *four pairs of 16-bit integers* which are *packed* inside the two operands, and then produces the high half of all four multiplies (Packed Multiply High - Word). This means that, for inputs 0x12345678abcdef01, 0x9876543210fedcba, it would multiply `0x1234 * 0x9876`, `0x5678 * 0x5432`, `0xabcd * 0x10fe`, `0xef01 * 0xdcba`, and pack the high 16 bits of each result into the output.

For your example, you're multiplying `0xffff * 0xffff` four times, producing the 32-bit result `0x00000001` (`-1 * -1`, since this is a signed 16-bit multiply), and therefore get `0x0000000000000000` in the high half and `0x0001000100010001` in the low half - which is exactly what you see in the `bitset` output.

---

If you're looking for a 128-bit multiply, there isn't actually an intrinsic for that (except `_mulx_u64`, but that uses the new `mulx` instruction which isn't that widespread). Microsoft has the non-standard `_mul128` intrinsic, but on other platforms you can just use a `__int128` type (or the local equivalent) to get a 64x64=>128 bit multiply.

Also, I'd seriously recommend using the SSE instruction set rather than the older MMX set; the SSE instructions are faster in most cases and enable you to operate on much wider vector types (256-bit is standard now, with AVX512 now available), which can provide a significant speed boost.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on this, but according to https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhw, these instructions don't do a 64x64->128 multiply; they do four 16x16->32 multiplies.  Note the word "packed" in the description.  Moreover it's a signed multiply.

So your 64-bit `UINT64_MAX` values are interpreted as four words of `0xffff`, which is to say `-1`.  So you are multiplying `-1` by `-1`, four times.  Of course the numerical answer to each one is `1`.  The result of the `pmulhw` instruction is the high halves of the results (i.e. four words of `0x0000`), and `pmullw` is the low halves (i.e. four words of `0x0001`).

Which is exactly what you got, so it seems to me the instructions are working perfectly.

If you want to do an unsigned multiply of two 64-bit integers, the plain old fashioned `mul` instruction will serve your purpose, and the easiest way to get `gcc` to generate it is probably by casting the inputs to `__uint128_t` and multiplying with the usual `*` operator.

Comment: It's actually surprising that GCC *doesn't* have an intrinsic for this (MSVC does, as `_umul128` and `_mul128`). Does GCC always generate good code for the casted multiply (i.e. does it avoid multiplying the zeroed high halves)? Regardless, +1.

Comment: @nneonneo: In my simple test it does: https://godbolt.org/z/pRq-Az